# To the certain tag in XML using JSOUP

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

```
<code code="43683-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="RECENT MAJOR CHANGES SECTION"/>
               <title/>
               <effectiveTime value="20111004"/>
               <excerpt>
                  <highlight>
                     <text>
                        <paragraph>Contraindications <linkHtml href="#s4">(4)</linkHtml>   10/2011</paragraph>
                        <paragraph>Warnings and Precautions, Use in Pregnant Women with Mechanical Heart Valves <linkHtml href="#s5.5">(5.5)</linkHtml>   10/2011</paragraph>
                     </text>
                  </highlight>
               </excerpt>
```

In this XML, I got to the tag `<code code="43683-2"...>` using

```
for (Element e : doc.select("code")) {
            if (e.attr("code").trim().equals("43683-2")){
            //codes
            }
}
```

Now, how can I get to the **first** `<highlight>` tag after the `<code code="43683-2"...>` tag?. There are multiple `<highlight>`  tags on the XML and I just want to get the first one after that specific code.

Since I have no previous experience on JSOUP or any other parsers, any help is extremely valuable.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nextElementSibling` method of `Element` class:

Ex:

```
for (Element e : doc.select("code")) {
    if (e.attr("code").trim().equals("43683-2")) {
        Element firstHighlight = null;     
        Element sibling = e.nextElementSibling();
        while (sibling != null && firstHighlight == null) {
            if (sibling.tagName().equals("highlight")) {
                firstHighlight = sibling;
            } else {
                sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It exactly didn't solve my problem but gave me a way to do it. Thank you so much.